# Facebook Analytics - how group events based on time (breakdown to 24 segments)

Tags: facebook-analytics

I want to know at **WHAT TIME** mostly my events happens during a period of time, so for example:

Event : Initiate Checkout 
time 00:00 ~ 01:00 = 80 events 
time 01:00 ~ 02:00 = 145 events 
time 02:00 ~ 03:00 = 300 events 
... 
time 23:00 ~ 24:00 = 20 events

between date range: 1 nov ~ 30 nov 2018 
Note : the results shouldn't be 720 (30*24) time fragments, but 24 time fragments.

How to do that using facebook analytics ?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to "Events" section, choose "Initiate Checkout", on the charts choose "Time Interval" as "Hourly". For date range, you can choose 1 nov ~ 30 nov on the top left corner.

Comment: this will make the results to be 30 * 24 = 720 dots. 
I want the results just 24 dots within those time range. Kind of classification of WHEN MOSTLY events HAPPENS during a period of time.